# NodeJS SIGKILL does not exists and throws error

Tags: node.js

I have implement in my node js app restart of node using terminal:

```
killall -9 node
```

i try to detect SIGKILL before node is actually killed with this code:

```
process.on('SIGKILL', function() {
    /* DO SOME STUFF HERE */

    process.exit()
})
```

but problem is that node does not recognize `SIGKILL` and throws an error while compiling...so my question is does anyone have idea how to detect `killall -9` command in node before node app is terminated so that i can do some stuff before killing node app?

I read on node web page that SIGKILL is reserved and is not used so i need alternative way how to detect `killall -9` command.... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using:

```
killall -2 node
```

`-2` define signal interrupt like `Ctrl+C` so node triggers SIGINT before exits because -2 simulates Ctrl+C...and voila problem solved.